# Where can an app fetch a public key to validate a signed key?

Tags: security, encryption-asymmetric

If I sign a public key with my own private key and the signed public key is loaded into a mobile app at runtime, how can the app validate the signature without embedding in the app the public key of the private key used to do the signing?

Makes sense?

What’s a secure place to grab the public key used for validation?

Perhaps it’s best to embed it. Little chance of tampering if it’s from App Store or Play Store. I can keep the private key on paper and worse case scenario everyone updates the app to get new public key.

Comment: What type of app? Webapp? Phone App? Microservice?

Comment: I meant mobile app. Updated...

Comment: We just embed the public key inside the app. Another approach would be to fetch the public key from the HTTPS certificate of a trusted public website managed by you.